# C++11 method to check whether template arguments are "invocable"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

C++17 introduced [std::invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable), but I'm wondering about C++11-only solution. My first thought is to use [std::result_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

My current code looks like this (`SchedulingPolicy` is an `enum class`):

```
template<typename Function, typename... Args,
    typename = typename std::result_of<Function&&(Args&&...)>::type>
int start(size_t stackSize, size_t queuedSignals, size_t signalActions,
    uint8_t priority, SchedulingPolicy schedulingPolicy, Function&& function,
    Args&&... args)
{
  // main implementation
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args,
    typename = typename std::result_of<Function&&(Args&&...)>::type>
int start(size_t stackSize, size_t queuedSignals, size_t signalActions,
    uint8_t priority, Function&& function, Args&&... args)
{
  return start(stackSize, queuedSignals, signalActions, priority,
      SchedulingPolicy::roundRobin, std::forward<Function>(function),
      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args,
    typename = typename std::result_of<Function&&(Args&&...)>::type>
int start(size_t stackSize, uint8_t priority, Function&& function,
Args&&... args)
{
  return start(stackSize, 0, 0, priority, SchedulingPolicy::roundRobin,
      std::forward<Function>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args,
    typename = typename std::result_of<Function&&(Args&&...)>::type>
int start(size_t stackSize, uint8_t priority,
    SchedulingPolicy schedulingPolicy, Function&& function, Args&&... args)
{
  return start(stackSize, 0, 0, priority, schedulingPolicy,
      std::forward<Function>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

There is basically one main implementation - with all possible arguments - and 3 wrappers - which don't have all arguments. I use SFINAE in the template arguments - `typename = typename std::result_of<Function&&(Args&&...)>::type` - as otherwise one of the wrappers causes infinite recursion. This seems to work fine, but I did only very limited testing. However on cppreference I've read the motivation for depreciation of `std::result_of` in favor of `std::invoke_result` (BTW the info there is why I'm using r-value references instead of `std::result_of<Function(Args...)>`), which made me wonder whether my use is correct or maybe there will be (real-life) situations where this will actually fail even though the passed arguments are correct? My use-case is passing all possible "callables": regular functions, member functions, lambdas or functors.

Comment: For the wrapper, I would use `auto wrapper(...) -> decltype(f(...))` avoiding the deprecated `std::result_of` use for SFINAE, and so only main implementation would have the deprecated code.

Comment: Provided links already state *"To avoid these quirks, result_of is often used with reference types as F and Args."* as you do.

Comment: Your recursion happenes in the wrapper that takes the least arguments (`int start(size_t stackSize, uint8_t priority, Function&& function,
          Args&&... args)`). If you don't restrict `function` to be a callable (via sfinae) the best template match will almost always be that wrapper because `Function&&` and `Args&&` are forwarding references (not rvalue references) and will always give you a perfect match for any argument. Only if your arguments match the parameter types exactly, overload resolution overrules sfinae.

Comment: Also, note that for c++11 `result_of` requires a well formed callable: _F must be a callable type, reference to function, or reference to callable type. Invoking F with ArgTypes... must be a well-formed expression._ That means, using `result_of` with a non-callable type or even the wrong argument types results in UB.